# Angular 7 - NG BUILD --PROD no funciona correctamente?

Tags: angular7

Estoy intentando desplegar una aplicacion web con Angular 7. Para generar el DIST, ejecuto el siguiente comando:

```
ng build --prod
```

y se genera la carpeta DIST. Esta carpeta yo la paso al nginx en el directorio correspondiente y todo funciona correctamente, EXCEPTO que cuando veo la consola del browser me dice que lo estoy corriendo en modo develop. Porque sucede esto si le puse --prod

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Solamente en la consola manda a llamar la funcion

```
enableProdMode()
```

Comment: en la consola antes de llamar a ng build --prod ?...o en la consola del browser?. Si es en la del browser, como hago para que todos los usuarios ejecuten esa opcion?

Comment: En el browser con que lo hagas una vez es suficiente, sino es que tu cache guarda la version developer, pero en si ya estas en prod